# SQL conditional Statements

Tags: postgresql, xtuple

I am attempting to get all the records from a table where trans_type='RM' but if there is no trans_type='RM' i want to return all the records where trans_type = 'AD'

Technically im using xtupls MetaSQL on a PostgreSQL server so a solution using either is great I can upload my metaSQL statement need be but I really just need a way to do

```
-- Group: lotserial 
-- Name: detail
-- Notes: 
-- Copyright (c) 1999-2014 by OpenMFG LLC, d/b/a xTuple.
-- See www.xtuple.com/EULA for the full text of the software license.

SELECT ls_number,
   ls_notes, 
   formatlotserialnumberbarcode(ls_number) AS lotserial_barcode,
   item_number, 
   item_descrip1, 
   item_descrip2,
   charass_char_id,
   charass_value,
   poitem_id,
   poitem_vend_item_descrip,
   char_name, 
   formatqty(itemloc_qty) as lotqty,
   lshist.*
FROM   
   itemloc, 
   ls
   JOIN item ON (item_id=ls_item_id)
   LEFT JOIN charass ON (charass_target_id=ls_id)
   LEFT JOIN "char" ON (char_id=charass_char_id),
   lshist (<? value("itemid") ?>,<? value("warehouseid") ?>,ls_number,
           <? value("pattern") ?>,<? value("transType") ?>,<? value("startDate") ?>,
           <? value("endDate") ?>,<? value("trace") ?>,1)


     LEFT JOIN pohead ON(pohead_number=(TRIM(SUBSTRING(lshist_ordernumber FROM '-.*-'),'-')))

     LEFT JOIN poitem ON(poitem_pohead_id=pohead_id)

   <? if exists('ls_id') ?>
   WHERE ls_id=<? value("ls_id") ?>
   <? endif ?>
   <? if exists('ls_number') ?>
   WHERE ls_number=<? value("ls_number") ?>
   <? endif ?>


   AND lshist_warehous_code='PS'

   <? if exists(TRIM(SUBSTRING(lshist_ordernumber FROM '.*-'),'-')='PO')?>
   AND poitem_linenumber = CAST(TRIM(SUBSTRING(lshist_ordernumber FROM '[^-]*$'),'-') AS INTEGER)
   <? endif ?>

   AND ls_id = itemloc_ls_id
   AND charass_target_type = 'LS'


 /*
   <? if exists(lshist_transtype='RM')?>
   AND lshist_transtype='RM'
   <? elseif exists(lshist_transtype='AD')?>
   AND lshist_transtype='AD'
   <? elseif exists(lshist_transtype='RL')?>
   AND lshist_transtype='RL' 
   <? elseif exists(lshist_transtype='SH')?>
   AND lshist_transtype='SH'  
   <? elseif exists(lshist_transtype='IM')?>
   AND lshist_transtype='IM'
    <? elseif exists(lshist_transtype='TR')?>
   AND lshist_transtype='TR'
   <? elseif exists(lshist_transtype='RP')?>
   AND lshist_transtype='RP' 
   <? endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just run two queries, the first with `WHERE trans_type='RM'`, and only run a second query with `WHERE trans_type='AD'` if the first one returns an empty result.

I think that trying to squish that into a single query would make things overly complicated and probably also would not be faster – I cannot think of a way that avoids a second scan.

Comment: I have multiple cases to test so it would be too much overhead

Comment: Overhead where? Maybe a few rond trips more, but I don't think there would be an overhead on the database side. I'd got with the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) here.

Comment: [My solution avoids the second scan as can be seen in the plan and the benchmarks](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/05/31/how-to-execute-a-sql-query-only-if-another-sql-query-has-no-results/)

Comment: I eventually had to split it into 2 query for simplicity and run speed. sorry for the bad question. I don't know a whole lot about this system but thanks for the help

Comment: @LukasEder Actually, I take that back. Your solution is not better than mine. You avoid a second sequential scan *only* if there are rows with `trans_type = 'RM'`, just like my solution does. If there is no such row, you'll get a second sequential scan, just like I do. The *only* advantage of your solution is that you sometimes avoid a second client-server round trip. But the price you pay is a) a more complicated query and b) more memory consumption on the server (materialization of the CTE).

Comment: Yes, that's what I said (I think?). And the CTE materialization overhead happens in PostgreSQL only, not in Oracle. So, I agree. In the context of this question, your solution will be better (except if the client-server round trip is really expensive). I just wanted to make sure that it is understood, that the database can avoid the second scan if it is not needed. This may be valuable in more complex situations. I've adapted my answer to take this into account.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a common table expression:

```
WITH rm AS (
  SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE trans_type = 'RM'
)
SELECT *
FROM data
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE trans_type = 'AD'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM rm
)
```

This will avoid the second scan as can be seen in an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` call, but there's still a little overhead compared to making the decision in the client, probably due to the CTE materialization (which is PostgreSQL-specific).

[I've benchmarked this for an small data set. There seems to be a 5% - 10% overhead in PostgreSQL over running two queries from pgplsql.](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/05/31/how-to-execute-a-sql-query-only-if-another-sql-query-has-no-results/) So, in most cases, and for simple queries like this one, [Laurenz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266019/521799) is preferrable.

There may be more complex query setups, where the single query is preferrable to two separate queries, as the single query can re-use intermediate results.

Comment: looks good accept I have to build the table based on parameters from other tables could

Comment: @calebbaker: Your edited question is an entirely different question than your original question. Can you please revert your edit and ask a new question here on Stack Overflow?